# How to print the value from roo uiModel?

Tags: spring-roo

When I print `uiModel ${subscribers}` in jspx page.  I am getting following:

```
"[Code: S0001, FirstName: John, 
               LastName: Smith, 
               Message: New subscriber, 
               Active: 1, 
               RouteID: Code: 1, 
               Name: Route 1, 
               Active: 1, 
               TruckID: 
  Code: t1000, 
               Name: Truck 1, 
               Active: 1, 
               DistrictID: 
  Code: dst1, 
               Name: Colombo 1, 
               Active: 1, 
               LastModifiedDate: 2011-04-02 15:40:25.0, 
               LastModifiedUser: admin, 
               LastModifiedDate: 2011-04-02 00:00:00.0, 
               LastModifiedUser: admin, 
               LastModifiedDate: 2011-04-02 00:00:00.0, 
               LastModifiedUser: admin, 
               PaymentTypeID: 

  Code: 1, 
               Name: Cash, 
               LastModifiedDate: 2011-04-02 00:00:00.0, 
               LastModifiedUser: admin, 
               LastModifiedDate: 2011-04-02 00:00:00.0, 
               LastModifiedUser: admin]"
```

How can I print the property "Code" only:

I tried the following but it print empty string:

```
${subscribers[Code]}
```

And I have one more question.  How to send multiple uiModels and display in form and update them?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you pushin the toString method that Roo have generated in the file "[Entityname]_Roo:ToString.aj" and reimplement it so it returns the value(s) that you want.
Something like:

```
public String [Entityname].toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Code: ").append(getCode());
        return sb.toString();
    }
```